# Prometheus Node-Exporter | Rate of total CPU Time > 100%

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-node-exporter

I am trying to make a CPU-Usage panel in Grafana for my Dashboard. While making the expression I noticed something odd:

As you can see in the Image the total of the samples for `cpu=10` are not exactly equal to 100%. The samples with `mode="idle"` and `mode="softirq"` already add up to 105,33%. How is that possible?

[image: Grafana Screenshot]

The PromQL expression is

```
rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{instance="...", cpu="10"}[1m])
```

I admit that once you average across `cpu` you end up very close to 100% but this bothers my perfectionist self. Does anyone know how to fix this or why this happens? My first thought was that it might be something related to calculating the rate

Comment: What does `sum(rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{instance="...", cpu="10"}[$__rate_interval]))` show? Rate is not exact, and produces a bit of extrapolation, but usually total for rates is closer to 1. IIRC, something like 0.98-0.99

Comment: @markalex The situation in the screenshot is an outlier. The values stay within 0.98 and 1 for the overwhelming majority of the time. If that is within the expected error, then so be it. Your expression results in a line bouncing around 1 from 0.985 up to 1.005 so I guess that confirms what you said about ´rate´

Comment: Well, maybe 1.05 not usual-usual situation, but definitely not [something unheard of](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=max_over_time(sum(rate(node_cpu_seconds_total%7B%7D%5B2m%5D))%5B1h%3A%5D)%20%2B%20on()%20group_left(name)%20absent(non_existent%7Bname%3D%22max%22%7D)%20*%200%0Aor%20min_over_time(sum(rate(node_cpu_seconds_total%7B%7D%5B2m%5D))%5B1h%3A%5D)%20%2B%20on()%20group_left(name)%20absent(non_existent%7Bname%3D%22min%22%7D)%20*%200%20%20%3E%200.5&g0.tab=0&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=4w)

Comment: It seems like some sudden changes of one of modes can result in this spikes. I'd say your occurrence maybe on the boundary of being normal, but I don't think you need to worry about it.